# How do I get all the entities for which at least one of the filter conditions is true?

Tags: 8, views

I set *Filter type to expose* to *Grouped filters*.

> [image: screenshot]

Then, I set the filter values.

> [image: screenshot]

The view returns entities for which all the conditions are true.
How can I get all the entities for which at least one of those conditions is true?